# Every client request is a new instance of the class?

Tags: php, oop

I wrote a class that builds some url in a page every time there is a client request to the server. In a hypothetical scenario in which 100 clients, at the same time, require a server connection, it should produce 100 instances of that class, right? 
So I would like to know what would be the result of many instances at the same time on the page and if this is a good practice to solve my problem with the "url generator".
Thanks

[EDIT]
What I tried to do it was to use __set() method and overloading to build the URLs. The fact is that I started to study object-oriented programming in php and I wanted to try a practical application of this method. Here is a piece of code:

```
 Class BuildPath { 

    private $ServerPath;
    private $ServerUrl;
    private $UrlPath;
    private $data;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->ServerPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        $this->ServerUrl =  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $this->UrlPath = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $this->data = array();
    }

    public function __get($key) {
            return $this->$key;
    }

    public function __set($key,$value)
    {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    // others methods
```

Comment: You might start by posting some code for people to take a look at ...

Comment: You will probably need to edit this so it is more clear what your goals are. As I read it, each client request is no different than any other visitor on a site that instantiates whatever classes the programmers tell it to. Are you asking about overloading a server with requests? We don't know that you even have a problem with "url generator" so we can't tell you anything about whether or not your question above can solve it.

Comment: @anemi I think you need to spend some time and clarify the problem for us. It's really unclear what you mean my "url generator". Maybe defining what problem you are trying to solve would be a good step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading some of the comments I think you are misunderstanding what PHP is and isn't. Each time a user makes a request to the page it is "creating an instance" as you say. After the page is loaded the "instance" is removed. This is how PHP works.

Singleton classes will not share data with one users instance with another users instance but instead share that users intsance of that class with that same users instance of another class.

This is how PHP operates and is normal. Since php doesn't "store" data between each request this is where memcache or mysql come into use or sessions.

Comment: thank you for your clarification. Actually what I meant was to "share" the class instances between different users requests..Can you suggest me some references about patterns in php?

Answer (score 2):

One thing to be aware of is that PHP has no application scope, meaning that there is no shared memory between requests. A database (mysql) or in memory store (memcache) is typically used to share the state of objects between requests.

Without knowing more specifics to your question, in general, each request made to the webserver will spawn a new instance of your class, but each class will only be aware of it's own state unless you have a mechanism to share it.

Comment: So if there isn't a memcache system to share the state of objects, the result would be a big waste of resources by the server with 100 or more active instances, right? What about a singleton pattern? It would be useful in a case like this? Thank you

Comment: No the issue wouldn't be solved by changing the pattern. I'm assuming what you are trying to do is build a URL shortener. What you need to do is have a class that generates URL's, checks to see if it already exists in the database, then stores them if they are unique (again in the database).